# Extracting letters until a comma with pandas and regex

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have this toy dataset, with locations from France:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3,4,5,6],'location':['Noisy-le-Sec, Seine-Saint-Denis, Île-de-France, France',\
                                                 'France','Paris, Paris, Île-de-France, France',\
                                                 'Orléans, Loiret, Centre-Val de Loire, France',\
                                                 'Dunkirk, Nord, Hauts-de-France, France',\
                                                 'Paris, France']})
df
    id  location
0   1   Noisy-le-Sec, Seine-Saint-Denis, Île-de-France...
1   2   France
2   3   Paris, Paris, Île-de-France, France
3   4   Orléans, Loiret, Centre-Val de Loire, France
4   5   Dunkirk, Nord, Hauts-de-France, France
5   6   Paris, France
```

And I want to create an additional column `redux` where I take the first words before a comma appears (the exception is when there is no comma, then I grab nothing). I tried this with regex, but I got NaNs:

```
df['redux'] = df['location'].str.extract(r'(^w,)')

    id  location                                            redux
0   1   Noisy-le-Sec, Seine-Saint-Denis, Île-de-France...   NaN
1   2   France                                              NaN
2   3   Paris, Paris, Île-de-France, France                 NaN
3   4   Orléans, Loiret, Centre-Val de Loire, France        NaN
4   5   Dunkirk, Nord, Hauts-de-France, France              NaN
5   6   Paris, France                                       NaN
```

The expected result is:

```
    id  location                                            redux
0   1   Noisy-le-Sec, Seine-Saint-Denis, Île-de-France...   Noisy-le-Sec
1   2   France                                              
2   3   Paris, Paris, Île-de-France, France                 Paris
3   4   Orléans, Loiret, Centre-Val de Loire, France        Orléans
4   5   Dunkirk, Nord, Hauts-de-France, France              Dunkirk
5   6   Paris, France                                       Paris
```

Please, any help or suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df['redux'] = df['location'].str.extract('(.+?),')
```

yielding

```
   id                                           location         redux
0   1  Noisy-le-Sec, Seine-Saint-Denis, Île-de-France...  Noisy-le-Sec
1   2                                             France           NaN
2   3                Paris, Paris, Île-de-France, France         Paris
3   4       Orléans, Loiret, Centre-Val de Loire, France       Orléans
4   5             Dunkirk, Nord, Hauts-de-France, France       Dunkirk
5   6                                      Paris, France         Paris
```

Comment: Thank you @Brendan, just a question, does the `?` sign convert the expression from greedy to lazy, so I only grab the first letters doesn't it?

Comment: @Alexis Correct -- see https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#greedy-versus-non-greedy

Answer (score 1):

Let us do

```
s = df.location.str.split(',')
df['new'] = np.where(s.str.len()==1,'',s.str[0])
df
Out[34]: 
   id                                           location           new
0   1  Noisy-le-Sec, Seine-Saint-Denis, Île-de-France...  Noisy-le-Sec
1   2                                             France              
2   3                Paris, Paris, Île-de-France, France         Paris
3   4       Orléans, Loiret, Centre-Val de Loire, France       Orléans
4   5             Dunkirk, Nord, Hauts-de-France, France       Dunkirk
5   6                                      Paris, France         Paris
```

Comment: Thank you @BENY for the solution, it was interesting to see that `where`can have a 'if-else` evaluation